# NoMethodError rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, renderpartial

I am building a side project rails app. One feature I am trying to implement is a text_field where a user submits a youtube link, and that creates an embedded video to be displayed on their own page. I am running into the NoMethodError when i go to /users/2 , i was hoping you guys could give a newbie a hand:

/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Users#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/show.html.erb</p>

<%= render partial: 'shared/track_form' %>
```

views/shared/_track_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@track) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Upload a youtube song URL..." %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

the error: `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

track.rb

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

I have a tracks controller, but I think it is trying to use the Users Controller..

anymore code or info that you need let me know, thank you.

Comment: is @track created in the show action of your users controller?

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you facing?? 
If your problem is related to **NoMethodError** only then let me know the more details like when its occurring and error report i.e. console part.

If your problem is with youtube part then this is your answer:

```
<iframe width='450' height='250' src='youtube_source' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Enter this code in your view part and replace youtube_source with your youtube_url

If you are using youtube url directly from url region then you have to do some customization with url.

E.g.

Normal youtube url from url region:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5euwZEE4Mo
```

And in iframe tag we require url like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/h5euwZEE4Mo
```

You can see the difference in both links (embed and watch?v)

Basically one thing is conman in both link i.e. the code at the end **h5euwZEE4Mo**.
So you need to extract this code from url, for extracting the code you can use this.

```
video_url = (/([\w-]{11})/.match(url)).to_s
```

Then you can use this url in iframe link this.

```
<iframe width='450' height='250' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=video_url%>' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```